# performFiltering accepts only CharSequence

Tags: android

I want to use custom filter class, but I dont know hot to filter data based on miltiple criteria. I do not want to pass CharSequence, but custom object containing strings, checkboches (boolean) etc..

Example filter dialog:

### [image: Example filter dialog]

Than you for help

Comment: If I good understood you. You can call toString method on CharSequence object.

Comment: So you advise to serialize to String and then deserialize back to object? Hmmm not pretty :)

Comment: But CharSequence is a interface and String in Android implements CharSequence I'm afraid that you doesn't have choice